# adjusting swept signal equation

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, octave

When I do a spectrogram in matlab / octave I can create a swept signal that looks like the RED plot line below.  But how can I create a swept signal like the BLUE line in the 1st plot using the equation below.

thanks to Daniel and David for getting me this far with the code is below

```
startfreq=200;
fs=44100;
endfreq=20;
dursec= 10;%duration of signal in seconds
t=(0:dursec*fs)/fs; %Time vector
alpha=log(startfreq/endfreq)/dursec;
sig = exp(-j*2*pi*startfreq/alpha*exp(-alpha*t));
sig=(sig/max(abs(sig))*.8); %normalize signal
wavwrite([sig'] ,fs,32,strcat('/tmp/del.wav')); %export file
specgram(sig,150,400);
```

**1st plot**
[image: Plot that I'm trying to reproduce]

---

**2nd plot**
[image: Plot with 200hz-20hz works]

---

How can I fix the the equation in the variable **sig** to get it to look like the BLUE line in the **1st plot**?

**3rd plot**
[image: Plot with 20hz-200hz which doesn't do what I want]

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is almost an month old, so you might have figured this out by now.  Here's an answer in case you are still interested.

It appears that your current model for the frequency is

```
freq(t) = b*exp(-alpha*t)
```

with

```
freq(0) = b = startfreq
freq(dursec) = b*exp(-alpha*dursec) = endfreq
```

There are two free parameters (`b` and `alpha`), and two equations.  The first equation, `b = startfreq`, gives us `b` (trivially).

Solving the last equation for `alpha` gives

```
alpha = -log(endfreq/startfreq)/dursec
      = log(startfreq/endfreq)/dursec
```

So

```
freq(t) = startfreq * exp(-alpha*t)
```

To use this as the instantaneous frequency of a frequency-swept signal,
we need the integral, which I'll call phase(t):

```
phase(t) = -(startfreq/alpha) * exp(-alpha*t)
```

The (complex) frequency-swept signal is then

```
sig(t) = exp(2*pi*j * phase(t))
```

The real part of this signal is

```
sig(t) = cos(2*pi*phase(t))
```

---

That explains your current code.  To generate a chirp whose frequency varies like the blue curve, you need a different model for the frequency.  A more general model than the one used above is

```
freq(t) = a + b*exp(-alpha*t)
```

The requirements at `t=0` and `t=dursec` are

```
freq(0) = a + b = startfreq
freq(dursec) = a + b*exp(-alpha*dursec) = endfreq
```

That's two equation, but we now have three parameters: `a`, `b`, and `alpha`.  I'll use the two equations to determine `a` and `b`, and leave `alpha` as a free parameter.  Solving gives

```
b = (startfreq - endfreq)/(1 - exp(-alpha*dursec))
a = startfreq - b
```

Integrating the model gives

```
phase(t) = a*t - (b/alpha)*exp(-alpha*t)
```

`alpha` is an arbitrary parameter.  Following the formula from the first model, I'll use:

```
alpha = abs(log(startfreq/endfreq))/dursec
```

The following is a complete script.  Note that I also changed the use of `exp(-j*2*pi*...)` to `cos(2*pi*...)`.  The factor `0.8` is there to match your code.

```
startfreq = 20;
endfreq = 200;
fs = 44100;
dursec = 10;  % duration of signal in seconds
t = (0:dursec*fs)/fs;  % Time vector

if (startfreq == endfreq)
    phase = startfreq * t;
else
    alpha = abs(log(endfreq/startfreq))/dursec;
    b = (startfreq - endfreq)/(1 - exp(-alpha*dursec));
    a = startfreq - b;

    phase = a*t - (b/alpha)*exp(-alpha*t);
endif

sig = 0.8 * cos(2*pi*phase);

wavwrite([sig'] ,fs,32,strcat('del.wav'));  % export file
specgram(sig,150,400);
```

Comment: thanks so much!!  What tweaks do I need to change to allow startfreq == endfreq?

Comment: I modified the script to handle `startfreq == endfreq`.